# Show marker/geopoint with existing sqlite database

Tags: android, google-maps

Anyone, please help me..

When i try to add location by long and lat on the source code, it's work.

But

when i tried to add location by existing database, i got force close.

here my source code :

```
private void initLokasi() {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = openOrCreateDatabase(
        "imsyakiyah.db"
        , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
        , null
        );
    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);

    Cursor cur = db.query("masjidmap", 
            null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            String nama_masjid = cur.getString(1);
            int latitude = cur.getColumnIndex("latitude");
            int longitude = cur.getColumnIndex("longitude");
            list_lokasi.add(new Lokasi(longitude,latitude, 1,nama_masjid));
        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    cur.close();
}
```

What should i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPLACE

```
int latitude = cur.getColumnIndex("latitude");
int longitude = cur.getColumnIndex("longitude");
```

WITH

```
int latitude = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
int longitude = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("longitude"));
```

Comment: i don't know why, when i try this..got error message "The method getColumnIndex(String) is undefined"

Comment: may i ask some question again?

Comment: do new question and put Android ,, as tag.. i will answer

Comment: ok, thanks. Here my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873746/got-force-close-on-sqlite-query-for-map-location-android